# Spacing between subfigure and subcaption

Tags: spacing, subfloats

Consider the code below.  I'm attempting to add space between the subfigures and their respective captions by modifying subfigcapskip (I've also tried skip, aboveskip, and captionskip), but I'm not getting the desired effect.  What is the correct property to specify?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption[subfigcapskip =50pt]{A blue square.}
\end{subfig}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \subcaption[subfigcapskip = 50pt]{A red square.}
\end{subfig}
\caption{Two squares.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optional argument to `\subcaption` is not for specifying settings, but for the caption to be used in the list of figures/tables.

You have to use `\captionsetup`, either globally or locally. I show you both methods:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=15pt} % global setting for subfigure

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{A blue square.}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\captionsetup{skip=50pt} % local setting for this subfigure
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{A red square.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Two squares.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want a global modification, and want, say, 10pt (the default is 6), use:

```
\usepackage[skip=10pt]{subcaption}
```

If it is only for subfigure environments:

```
\captionsetup{subfigure]{skip=10pt}
```

It you want to modify only for some subfigures:

```
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
   \captionsetup{skip=10pt}
   ......
```