# What controls the separation from bottom of pics to the sub titles, please?

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{book} %
\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{titletoc} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % define colors, color table, order important
    \definecolor{DarkCream}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,0.85} % FFFFFB
    \definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.00} % #880000
\usepackage[margin=10pt,
            font=normalsize,
            labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=space,
            position=below]{caption} %
\usepackage[position=below,
            textfont=normal,
            labelfont=bf]{subfig} %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt; 1pt=0.3515mm
%
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\center
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=105.8mm,toptitle=12pt,colframe=DarkRed,colback=DarkCream,top=4.8pt,bottom=4.8pt, left=0pt, right=0pt,arc=2pt,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=1.0pt,bottomtitle=26pt]
    \centering
\arrayrulecolor{blue!50!black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hspace{4.8pt}}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a}
&
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b} \\
\parbox{50mm}{\captionof{subfigure}{Inequality region \label{fig:inequalityregion}}}
&
\parbox{50mm}{\captionof{subfigure}{Proof of inequality \label{fig:inequalityproof}}}
\end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\vspace{-4pt}
    \caption{Region satisfying the inequality}
\label{fig:twodiminequalityregion}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Does it help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160935/spacing-between-subfigure-and-subcaption ?

Comment: You can use the optional argument for ` \\ ` as in `\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b} \\[-10pt]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the sub captions are placed in tabular environment, therefore you need control distance between successive rows. This is simple done with

```
\\[<value>]
```

If the value is positive, than you **increase** distance, contrary, negative value **decrease** it. See snippet of your code below:

```
\begin{figure}[h]\center
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=105.8mm,toptitle=12pt,
                      colframe=DarkRed,colback=DarkCream,
                      top=4.8pt,bottom=4.8pt,left=0pt,right=0pt, arc=2pt,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=1.0pt,
                      bottomtitle=26pt]
    \centering
\arrayrulecolor{blue!50!black}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hspace{4.8pt}}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-a}
&
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b} 
        \\[-1em]%<--- for control distance between 
                % images and sub-captions: for increasing 
                % use positive value, for decreasing negative
\parbox{50mm}{\captionof{subfigure}{Inequality region \label{fig:inequalityregion}}}
&
\parbox{50mm}{\captionof{subfigure}{Proof of inequality \label{fig:inequalityproof}}}
\end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\vspace{-4pt}%<--- in normal circumstances this vertical distance 
             % managed globally by option "skip"
    \caption{Region satisfying the inequality}
\label{fig:twodiminequalityregion}
\end{figure}
```

For selected `-1em` you should obtain the following figure:

[image]

and for `1em` the distance increase (a lot):

[image]

**Edit:**
Reducing distance between images and captions manually in each figure is not right way to manage this problem. Better way is set this distance globally with caption option `skip`, for example:

```
\usepackage[margin=10pt,
            font=normalsize,
            labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=space,
            position=below,
            skip=6pt]{caption} %
```

For details, please read documentation for caption section 2.6 Skips on page 13.

Comment: @keith77777, see edit of my answer in which I correct typing errors and add explanation how to manage vertical distance between caption and image. This time maybe is time to up-vote my answer too (not just accept it) :-)