# Spacing between tikz subfigures and subcaptions

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, subcaption

I'm having trouble reducing the size between the subcaptions and their figures when adding the figures through `tikz`. I tried a negative `\vspace` as well as setting (or changing?) the `\captionsetup{skip=...}` according to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160935/spacing-between-subfigure-and-subcaption) answer but nothing seems to work. Any help is very appreciated :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\subaxeswest}[5]{
\hspace{-25pt}
\subfloat[#5]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (image) at (0,0) [inner sep=6pt]{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}};
    \draw [->] (image.south west) -- ++(0.5,0) node[right]{\footnotesize #3};
    \draw [->] (image.south west) -- ++(0,0.5) node[above]{\footnotesize #4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{skip=-10pt} % this doesn't have any effect at all??
\vspace{-10pt}            % this neither
}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \subaxeswest{0.45}{example-image-a}{y}{x}{caption one}
        \quad
        \subaxeswest{0.45}{example-image-b}{y}{z}{caption two}
        \caption{Foo}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your preamble, you have to use `captionsetup` command for `subfloat`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\newcommand{\subaxeswest}[5]{
\hspace{-25pt}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{captionskip=-15pt}
\subfloat[#5]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (image) at (0,0) [inner sep=6pt]{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}};
      \draw [->] (image.south west) --++ (0.5,0) node[right]{\footnotesize #3};
    \draw [->] (image.south west) --++ (0,0.5) node[above]{\footnotesize #4};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \subaxeswest{0.45}{example-image-a}{y}{x}{caption one}
        \quad
        \subaxeswest{0.45}{example-image-b}{y}{z}{caption two}
         \caption{Foo}
    \end{figure}

     \begin{figure}[h!]
     \subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-1:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
     }
     \quad
     \subfloat[First sub-figure\label{subfig-2:dummy}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}
     }
     \caption{Baz}
     \label{fig:dummy}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want it for **all** the pictures, just the ones with the extra axes.

Comment: @Superuser27, If I understand your question correctly, I have edit my answer.

Comment: Mmh no, the axes are fine where I have them, but I have some pictures with and some without axes. I want *only* the ones with axes to have the captions closer to the pictures. With your first solution all subfigures' captions are moved, how can I move only the ones with axes?

Comment: @Superuser27, I think, I understood right now :-)